# n-tier-application, what goes where and assembly names

Tags: .net, architecture

I have created a project, that i need to split op in a n-tier-application (3 layers)

I started with one project, and startet to added all my classes. fx

```
public IServiceFoo()
{
  DoIt();
}

public ServiceFoo : IServiceFoo
{
  ...
}
```

Added IoC and all that.
Started to refactor, but hit a wall.
I have 4 Assemblies.

1. Model/Domain
2. Service/Infrastructure
3. DAL
4. ASP.NET MVC as view.

Where do I stick my IServiceFoo interface ??
The only logical place is in the Domain/Model assembly, because all other project knows that on, and therefor can be used a crossed the application.

Do I call my assembly: Domain instad of Model, since it is no longer only models ?

The same goes for Service ? that is more a Infrastructure since it constains Service classes and calculation logic .

Hope you can help ?
Thx.

-- EDIT - 08142012 --
My solution domain: A shop, for education and better know-how of architecture.

```
Solution (a 3 layers application :D then!)
  DAL - assembly (only pulls data up and save data)
    - ProductDAL : IProductDal
    - GroupDAL : IGroupDAL
    - UserDAL : IUserDAL

  Service - assembly
    - ProductService : IProductService (calculate products, load product by DAL)
    - GroupService : IGroupService (do some stuff with group, maybe delete group in list with no product)
    - UserService : IUserService (validate if a user can login, load user by dal, check password)
  Models - assembly
    - Product
    - Group
    - User
- Webshop - assembly (ASP.NET MVC) (with all the viewmodel and models, UI Helpers)
          Using DI/IoC as the glue, that sticks it all to getter.
```

Also: the webshop reference all assemblies. The service and dal layer knows noting of each other, other than the interface.

Where is the best place for my interface for Service and DAL ?
Hope this helps :S

Comment: make it an `n+1` tier application

Comment: Tiers are different than layers.  Tiers are distributed amongst multiple computers or processes.  Layers are within a single process.

Comment: What is IServiceFoo and ServiceFoo for?  We can't really tell you where it goes if we don't know what it's for and how it's going to be used.

Comment: This question probably isn't right for the technical Q&A format of StackOverflow. Specifically, there is no "right" answer to this question. It would probably find a better home over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ where this kind of more general question would be well-received.

Comment: k, that maybe. Is it possible to moved this thread. Or do I need to create a new question on the right thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Layering rules are that dependencies go in one way and one layer can only connect to two other layers (layer above and layer below).  Once you define what layer your assemblies go in, you must ensure that how they are referenced in your projects match that rule.  A lower layer cannot "reference" a higher layer.  If you break those rules, then your types are not in the right assemblies.

[image]

In this diagram BL "connects" to two other layers, the layer above (UI) and the layer below (DA).  The arrow shows that the UI takes a references to BL but the BL does not take a reference to the UI layer.  Same with BL and DA, BL takes a reference on DA, but DA does not take a reference on BL.

Comment: I think you may have contradicted yourself there. "Dependencies go one way" and "One layer can only connect to two other layers (above and below)" seem to contradict..

Comment: A lower layer can only have a dependency on a higher level and a higher layer is only *used* by a lower level.  That's a "connection" to two other layers--not a "dependency".

Comment: Again, I find your explanation confusing.. I'm not saying I think you're wrong.. I'm just saying I don't understand your explanation :)

Comment: Ahhhh. I get what you mean by "connections" now (thanks for the diagram) :)

Comment: If you have the Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate (2010 or better); you can create a layer diagram that defines what assemblies (or namespaces/classes, I believe) are in what layer.  that diagram can then "validate" that the items within layers have the correct dependencies.  e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409395(v=vs.100).aspx